# invalid option ORA-06512

Tags: sql, oracle

if I run the following query I get ORA-00922 and ORA-06512 as error messages.
Query should be right, what am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE
    query clob;
BEGIN
    query := 'create table cs_trassen_hists_' || to_char(current_date) || ' as select * from cs_trassen_hist';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
END;
```

Comment: but I want it to have the date of the time where the query is running.
In this format yyyymmdd

Comment: Use `dbms_output.put_line`, check the code generated and validate it by yourself

Comment: To me such an approach looks like poor database design. You should not create dynamically tables having names depending on current date. Better have one table which has a column say collection_date, which should also be partition key andjust insert select into that table, having the collection_date column filled-in with the required date.

Answer (score 0):

You should've specified format, as @Mat commented (it seems that you didn't get the point).

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     query  CLOB;
  3  BEGIN
  4     query :=
  5           'create table cs_trassen_hists_'
  6        || TO_CHAR (CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyymmdd')        --> this
  7        || ' as select * from dept';
  8
  9     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
 10  END;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from cs_trassen_hists_20230713;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```